# How to safely unwrap a CompletableException

Tags: java, completable-future

I'm trying to figure out a way in which when working with `CompletableFuture` to safely and without repeating the same code throughout my codebase, handle the `CompletionException` thrown when calling `CompletableFuture.join()`.

The behavior I'm looking for is - If the cause of the exception is any **unchecked** exception, then it should be thrown as-is. If the cause is **checked**, then wrap it in some form of `RuntimeException` (I've used the base `RuntimeException` class for this example, but in a real application I'd use a custom derived class) and throw the wrapper exception.

So far, I've come up with the following utility function to do the unwrapping:

```
public static RuntimeException unwrapCompletionException(CompletionException e) {
    Throwable cause =  e.getCause();
    if (cause instanceof RuntimeException) {
        return (RuntimeException) cause;
    } else if (cause instanceof InterruptedException) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        return new RuntimeException(e.getCause());
    } else {
        // Any other checked exception
        return new RuntimeException(e.getCause());
    }
}
```

And for example, the utility function could be used as so:

```
try {
    completableFuture.join();
} catch (CompletionException e) {
    throw unwrapCompletionException(e);
} catch (CancellationException e) {
    // Handled separately...
}
```

My question is about the safety of this approach and the completeness of the unwrapping code. Like for example, `InterruptedException` was one special case I could think of to handle, but maybe others exist as well. Maybe there are other consequences I didn't consider. Is my utility function missing anything in order to do what I'm intending when handling `CompletionException` in any circumstance?

Comment: You can also use `CompletableFuture exceptionally() ` to access thrown exceptions from the underlying code directly; nor sure if that improves the code overall, but then you could skip the `ExecutionException` unwrap afterwards.

Comment: That's a good point @daniu, but in this case I'd like to give the option to let exceptions be passed back to the caller.

Comment: Why do you think, throwing `new RuntimeException(e.getCause())` is better than the `CompletionException` you have caught?